# Clarifai API FACE_DETECT_MODEL showing 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple face-detecting react app. I used the Clarifai API's FACE_DETECT_MODEL which is showing the error

```
POST https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b/outputs 404 (Not Found)
```

on my console. The other models like COLOR_MODEL are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure if your function looks something like this if you are on `node.js` or a `react` app, replace `puppy.jpeg` with your image

```js
yourFunction(){
  app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, "https://samples.clarifai.com/puppy.jpeg")
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    },
    function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    );
  }
```